# How do you rearrange a list of strings based given certain conditions?

Tags: list-manipulation, associations

I had looked at previous answers for this but was unable to find a solution.  I have the following code:

```
dnames1={"A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6"}
dnumber={20,20,11,21,19,20}

newdnumber=TakeSmallest[dnumber,6]


AssociationThread[dnames,dnumber]
```

The positions of the strings given in "dnames1" correspond to the values in the same position given by list "dnumber" (this can be seen through the `AssociationThread`).  I then rearranged the list "dnumber" to go from the smallest number to the largest, giving a new list designated "newdnumber."  I'm trying to then produce a new corresponding list called "newdnames1" which reflects the new ordering given by "newdnumber."  This would give an output of:

```
newdnames1={"A3","A5","A1","A2","A6","A4"}
```

I've tried the following to solve this question:

```
assoc=AssociationThread[dnumber,dnames1]
newdnumber/.assoc
```

but the main issue is that the `AssociationThread`does not associate the correct list of strings if there are repeating values given in dnumber (I.e. The number 20 appears 3 times but the association only ever assigns "A6"`a value of 20 and it never assigns strings "A1" or "A2".  Any help producing newdnames1 would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why not just `dnames1[[Ordering[dnumber]]]` to get `newdnames1` directly?

Comment: If you insist on using associations, you could use `Keys@Sort@AssociationThread[dnames1, dnumber]`

Answer (score 1):

You can get `newdnames1` directly using

```
dnames1[[Ordering[dnumber]]]
```

If you you want to work with associations, for `newdnumber`, you can get the desired result simply using `Sort`:

```
assoc1 = AssociationThread[dnames1, dnumber]
```

> ```
> <|"A1" -> 20, "A2" -> 20, "A3" -> 11, "A4" -> 21, "A5" -> 19,   "A6" -> 20|>
> ```

```
assoc2b = Sort[assoc1]
```

> ```
>  <|"A3" -> 11, "A5" -> 19, "A1" -> 20, "A2" -> 20, "A6" -> 20,  "A4" -> 21|>
> ```

```
Keys @ assoc2
```

> ```
>  {"A3", "A5", "A1", "A2", "A6", "A4"}
> ```

For general  `newdnumber`, you can sort `assoc1` using `SortBy[PositionIndex[newdnumber]]`:

```
assoc2 = SortBy[PositionIndex[newdnumber]]@assoc1
```

> ```
> <|"A3" -> 11, "A5" -> 19, "A4" -> 21, "A1" -> 20, "A2" -> 20,  "A6" -> 20|>
> ```

```
Keys @ assoc2
```

> ```
>  {"A3", "A5", "A1", "A2", "A6", "A4"}
> ```

```
SeedRandom[1]

shuffledDnumber = RandomSample[dnumber]
```

> ```
>  {19, 11, 20, 20, 21, 20}
> ```

```
assoc3 = SortBy[PositionIndex[shuffledDnumber]]@assoc1
```

> ```
> <|"A5" -> 19, "A3" -> 11, "A4" -> 21, "A1" -> 20, "A2" -> 20,  "A6" -> 20|>
> ```

```
Keys @ assoc3
```

> ```
> {"A5", "A3", "A4", "A1", "A2", "A6"}
> ```